# Core Data crash during mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification

Tags: core-data, exc-bad-access

I have a rare crash that happens randomly in Core Data private/internal methods.

My setup:

- two NSPSC: mainPSC and importPSC
- MOC attached to importPSC runs in
  background and performs save
- Another object listens to
  DidSaveNotification and then merges importerMOC with mainMOC
  (attached to mainPSC)

This is all on iOS 9.3.
This is the code that runs on main thread (it's from my library [RTCoreDataStack](https://github.com/radianttap/RTCoreDataStack)):

```
[self.mainManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    [self.mainManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}];
```

I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS with various codes (EXC_I386_GPFLT on Simulator or SIGSEGV on device) in the crash reports. Here's one example:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000180eedb90 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreData                             0x0000000183773010 -[NSManagedObjectContext _mergeRefreshObject:mergeChanges:withPersistentSnapshot:] + 132
2   CoreData                             0x00000001837745fc -[NSManagedObjectContext _mergeChangesFromDidSaveDictionary:usingObjectIDs:] + 2276
3   CoreData                             0x000000018377cd04 __90+[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSCoreDataSPI) _mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:intoContexts:]_block_invoke1353 + 68
4   CoreData                             0x000000018377508c developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 192
5   CoreData                             0x0000000183774f54 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 216
6   CoreData                             0x000000018377c698 +[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSCoreDataSPI) _mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:intoContexts:] + 3420
7   CoreData                             0x0000000183774bb0 -[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:] + 384
8   RTCoreDataStack                      0x00000001005e8d34 __43-[RTCoreDataManager handleMOCNotification:]_block_invoke (RTCoreDataManager.m:294)
9   CoreData                             0x000000018377508c developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 192
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001812c147c _dispatch_client_callout + 12
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001812c6b84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1840
12  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018182cd50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
13  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018182abb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1624
14  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181754c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
15  GraphicsServices                     0x000000018303c088 GSEventRunModal + 176
16  UIKit                                0x0000000186a3e088 UIApplicationMain + 200
17  MyApp                         0x0000000100131910 main (main.m:14)
18  ???                                  0x00000001812f28b8 0x0 + 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind soul pointed me towards the possibility that these kind of crashes happens when you are using KVO to monitor a property of NSMO.

At first I tried to replace my own KVO code with Facebook's KVOController, but it did not help. Then I removed the KVO entirely and crashes went away.

Thus first conclusion is that **crash happens when KVO is setup over an object which gets deleted from the store during the merge happening on DidSaveNotification**.

Additionally for my case - it's not just KVO itself but also the fact that the objects I KVO-ed were added to a NSSet which was set as `property(assign)`. I'm currently testing KVO + `strong` reference.